# Starting an application when starting Apache Server

Tags: java, apache, statistics, server

Is there a way to start a Java application when launching Apache Server? I need to generate a report of the server's statistics, periodically, with a separate application.

Comment: How is the server launched? It would be trivial to just add a line like `java -jar /path/to/jar` to your launch script.

Comment: The server is launched normally from the Apache Monitor, but I think I'll end up doing a launch script or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows: Create a batch file; which will start both Apache and Tomcat services one after another. See below:

```
sc start MyService
```

Comment: @Kat Could you please elaborate your requirement? What I understood is you have Apache running on Windows box/server and a java standalone application which you would like to get started along with Apache.

Comment: The ideal situation would be to initiate one normally and that one alone initiate the other, but seeing how I haven't found a configuration that manages that, I'm gonna try the batch, thanks!